# How can I close the position with 4 criteria in pine script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

**After entry**, I would like to set the **Stop Loss according to 4 different criteria** and it will automatically close the position after the criteria are met. But the strategy.exit with stop loss part seems not accurate.

1. If the **price immediately falls below "Vegas channel" after entry** and the "**Volume Osc**" indicator **is above the 144** parameter line, then we **immediately stop loss at the current price** of that time.
2. If the **price immediately falls below "Vegas channel" after entry** and the "**Volume Osc**" indicator **is below 144**, continue to **observe whether there is an accelerated decline** (eg: decline **5%**) **within 24 hours**. If there is **no acceleration**, set the **stop loss at the support level**.
3. If there is **no significant acceleration after the break**, but it still **cannot return to the top of the Vegas channel within 24 hours**, we also make a stop loss, and the **final stop loss position is set below the "Vegas channel"**.
4. If the **price no falls below "Vegas channel"**, then set the **stop loss at usual at 6%**.

Remark: Vegas channel=the track between ema144 & ema169

```
strategy("Vegas", overlay=true, precision=2, pyramiding=6, initial_capital=6000)

//---Volume Oscillator---
var cumVol = 0.
cumVol += nz(volume)
if barstate.islast and cumVol == 0
    runtime.error("No volume is provided by the data vendor.")
shortlen = input.int(1, minval=1, title = "Short Length")
longlen = input.int(14, minval=1, title = "Long Length")
short = ta.ema(volume, shortlen)
long = ta.ema(volume, longlen)
osc = 100 * (short - long) / long

//---Support and Resistance Levels---
leftBars  = input(15, title = "Left Bars ")
rightBars  = input(15, title = "Right Bars")
volumeThresh  = input(20, title = "Volume Threshold")
highUsePivot = fixnan(ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)[1])
lowUsePivot = fixnan(ta.pivotlow(leftBars, rightBars)[1])
r1 = plot(highUsePivot, color=ta.change(highUsePivot) ? na : #ff113d,  linewidth=3, offset=-(rightBars+1), title="Resistance")
s1 = plot(lowUsePivot, color=ta.change(lowUsePivot) ? na : #007bff,  linewidth=3, offset=-(rightBars+1), title="Support")

//---Settings---
pc=input.float(title="tpsl percent",defval=6)/100
ordersize=1000/close

vegas_long = (out144>out576 and out169>out576) and (out144>out676 and out169>out676)
vegas_short = (out144<out576 and out169<out576) and (out144<out676 and out169<out676)
vegas_max = math.max(out144,out169)
vegas_min = math.min(out144,out169)
distance_long = low-vegas_max
distance_short = vegas_min-high
vegas_long2 = out12>out144 and out12>out169
vegas_short2 = out12<out144 and out12<out169
opengap = input.int(title="Next Position Gap", defval=1)
dist_min = input.float(title="Min Distance", defval=1)
dist_max = input.float(title="Max Distance", defval=25)

//---Long---
longCondition = vegas_long and vegas_long2 and (low>vegas_max and distance_long>dist_min and distance_long<=dist_max)

if longCondition and (strategy.position_size == 0 or (strategy.position_size > 0 and close<strategy.position_avg_price and strategy.position_avg_price-close>=opengap))

longTP_pc  = strategy.position_avg_price*(1+pc)
longSL_pc  = strategy.position_avg_price*(1-pc)
longSL_support = lowUsePivot

if strategy.position_size > 0 and (barstate.isnew and ta.crossunder(strategy.position_avg_price,vegas_max) and osc > 144)
    strategy.exit("Close Long","Long", limit=longTP_pc, stop=close, alert_message = "Close Long")

if strategy.position_size > 0 and (barstate.isnew and ta.crossunder(strategy.position_avg_price,vegas_max) and osc < 144)
    strategy.exit("Close Long","Long", limit=longTP_pc, stop=longSL_support, alert_message = "Close Long")

if strategy.position_size > 0 and (barstate.isnew and osc < 144)
    strategy.exit("Close Long","Long", limit=longTP_pc, stop=longSL_pc, alert_message = "Close Long")
```

Comment: Where exactly do you need help? What have you tried so far? What is working and what is not working in your code?

Comment: For the strategy.exit part, to set the stop loss bases on different SL criteria. I not sure whether it can be used this way. 
If criteria1
   strategy.exit("Close Long","Long", limit=longTP_pc, stop=close)
If criteria2
   strategy.exit("Close Long","Long", limit=longTP_pc, stop=longSL_support)
If criteria3
   strategy.exit("Close Long","Long", limit=longTP_pc, stop=longSL_pc)